# Create smooth curve from several points and get position on that curve by percent or time 

Tags: java, 2d, curve

I'm not good at math;/

I have array of 2D points P[n] (P1,P2...Pn)

What i want to do is to create a smooth curve based on that points ( like Bezier Curve but more complex ) and then get position on that curve based on time (t>=0;t<=1), when t=0 -> res = P1, when t=1 -> res = Pn, and when t = 0.5f somewhere in the middle.

Can you help me ? I think http://mathworld.wolfram.com/B-Spline.html is the right way to do this, but i need this in java.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a bspline is what you need.

Google showed this at the first result

http://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/Splines/Bspline.java

It is an applet, but it shows how to translate the maths.

Comment: yes, but i think something is wrong in that code, i've executed it and the result is some straight lines

Comment: Yes, that is because it has no X/Y data in it as it is applet wanting you to draw the data in but the functions in it show you how to draw a bspline - you can take that bit of code and work on it. If that doesn't help, googling "java bspline" will get you many more pages of java code to do it.